# Posting an array of emails to Mailchimp API

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, mailchimp

I have this code:

```
 <?php

       $gregorianMonth = date('n');
       $gregorianDay = date('j');
       $gregorianYear = date('Y');

       $jdDate = gregoriantojd($gregorianMonth,$gregorianDay,$gregorianYear); 

       $hebrewMonthName = jdmonthname($jdDate,4);

       $hebrewDate = jdtojewish($jdDate); 

       list($hebrewMonth, $hebrewDay, $hebrewYear) = split('/',$hebrewDate); 

        echo "<p style='color:#000000; font-size:11px'>Today's Hebrew Date: $hebrewDay $hebrewMonthName $hebrewYear</p>";

      $table_name = "candle_number";
      global $wpdb;
      $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT email FROM `{$table_name}` WHERE date_pref = \"hebrew\" AND datehebrew LIKE \"$hebrewDay $hebrewMonthName 5%\"");

      $final_output = array();

      foreach( $results as $rs ){

      $final_output[] = $rs->email;

}

      echo json_encode($final_output);

      echo count($final_output, COUNT_RECURSIVE);

      $automation_id = 'ed6e9exxxx';
      $api_key = '206b84dd296928a4b134b18xxxxxxxxx-us10';
      $email = $_POST[ implode(",",$final_output)];

      hebrew_date_mail($automation_id, $api_key, $email);
 ?>
```

and since it is Wordpress, I added this to the `functions.php` file:

```
 <?php
 function hebrew_date_mail($automation_id, $api_key, $email){
 $data = array(
    'apikey' => $api_key,
    'email_address' => $email,
 );
 $mch_api = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/automations/' . $automation_id . '/emails/491fec26f1/queue');
curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/2.0');
 curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
 curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
 curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data) ); 
 }
```

Basically what it does is checks the Hebrew date and month, and if any user in the DB matches, it sends to my MC API automation. However It is not working, and I think it has to do with the results array.

The problem is that I do not understand `cURL` or `JSON` very well yet, and I don't exactly know why this isn't working. Thank you.

Comment: is your site is http or https?

Comment: THIS site is https I believe